# node-graphviz does not generate the expected png file

Tags: graphviz

I am new to `node-graphviz`, which is a Node.js interface to the GraphViz graphing tool.

I want to draw a directed graph and save it into memory using the code:

```
var graphviz = require('graphviz');
var debug = true;

function draw (hbGraph) {
    /** Create the digraph */
    var vGraph = graphviz.digraph('Happens-Before-Graph'),
        eventNodes = {};

    /** Create nodes for digraph */

    for (var i = 0; i < hbGraph.eventNodes.length; i++) {
        /** Note, eventNodes is a sparse array */
        var event = hbGraph.eventNodes[i];
        if (event != undefined) {
            var node = vGraph.addNode(event.id, {
                'color': common.COLOR.GREY,
                'style': common.STYLE,
            });
            eventNodes[node.id] = node;
        }
    }

   /** Create edges for digraph, just ignore for this question */

   if (debug) {
        // Create digraph G
        var g = graphviz.digraph("G");

        // Add node (ID: Hello)
        var n1 = g.addNode( "Hello", {"color" : "blue"} );
        n1.set( "style", "filled" );

        // Add node (ID: World)
        g.addNode( "World" );

        // Add edge between the two nodes
        var e = g.addEdge( n1, "World" );
        e.set( "color", "red" );

        // Print the dot script
        console.log( g.to_dot() );

        // Set GraphViz path (if not in your path)
        g.setGraphVizPath( "/usr/local/bin" );
        // Generate a PNG output
        g.output( "png", "test01.png" );
    }

  console.log( vGraph.to_dot() );
  vGraph.setGraphVizPath( "/usr/local/bin" );
  vGraph.output('png', 'test02.png');
}
```

After running the code, file `test01.png` is generated while file `test02.png` is not without any exception. Both two results of `to_dot()` methods are successfully printed on the console.
The printout of `to_dot()` method for `test02.png` is:

```
digraph Happens-Before-Graph {
  "1" [ color = "grey" ];
  "7" [ color = "grey" ];
  "8" [ color = "grey" ];
  "9" [ color = "grey" ];
  "10" [ color = "grey" ];
  "11" [ color = "grey" ];
  "12" [ color = "grey" ];
  "13" [ color = "grey" ];
  "14" [ color = "grey" ];
}
```

I want to why file `test02.png` is not generated and how it can be generated. Could anyone help me?
In addition, the documenation about this library cannot be generated, so I am unfamiliar with it.
Additional information: link to node-graphviz is [node-graphviz](https://github.com/glejeune/node-graphviz)

Comment: When debugging above code, I just run the code creating nodes without code that creating edges. In order to generate the png file, must I add the code creating edges?

Comment: Very nice that the `to_dot` output is given this is lacking quite often in questions, it gives people without using `Node.js` the possibility to test the output as well!! I ran the mentioned output in http://www.webgraphviz.com/ and didn't get an picture either, but I saw the minus signs (`-`) in the digraph name and when changing these in underscores or completely removing them the image appears. See also https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html

Comment: @albert. You are right. After I remove the minus sign `-` in the digraph name, the code generates picture successfully. Sorry for this late reply and thanks a lot!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is just to remove the minus sign `-` in the digraph.
Since the documentation of `node-graphviz` cannot be built, I just post the right answer here.